# Android - Keeping action overflow but disable ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

How do I keep action overflow menu but disable rest of the ActionBarActivity in android?

I have searched here and on Google, most questions is about how to disable overflow menu.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy enough by implementing a custom ViewGroup extending from any Layout.

Just implement `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and make it return true this will give all the events to your root layout and then in your layouts `onTouchEvent()` make it return false so this means you snatch away all the touch event in your windows content view and don't consume them.

The action bar should run fine along with the overflow.

Just a tip though users generally don't appreciate seeing a bunch of views in an activity's window not responding to touch events.